# Most appropriate conversion of .mat file for database purposes

Tags: python, json, matlab, numpy, pickle

I am trying to create a database of my experimental results that with a very flexible structure (as different experiments require different experimental conditions). For now, I am thinking about going with JSON as the most appropriate format due to its "dictionary-like" nature.

My raw data files come in as Matlab files (.mat extension) but I have noticed that after conversion, I get an increase in file size by almost a factor of 10. I tried different conversion methods but they all give me a huge file increases and I was wondering whether this is an inherent problem with the formats I have chosen or whether there can be anything done with it.

Here is a sample code, I have created to test the conversion efficiency and a sample file I run through:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as spio
import json
import pickle
import os

def json_dump(data):
    with open('json.txt.','w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data,outfile)
    print 'JSON file size: ', os.path.getsize('json.txt')/1000, ' kB'

def pickle_dump(data):
    with open('pickle.pkl','w') as outfile:
        pickle.dump(data,outfile)
    print 'Pickle file size: ', os.path.getsize('pickle.pkl')/1000, ' kB'

def numpy_dump(data):
    np.save('numpy.npy',data)
    print 'NPY file size: ', os.path.getsize('numpy.npy')/1000, ' kB'

    np.savetxt('numpy.txt',data)
    print 'Numpy text file size: ', os.path.getsize('numpy.txt')/1000, ' kB'

def get_data(path):
    data = spio.loadmat(path)
    del data['__function_workspace__']
    del data['__globals__']
    del data['__version__']
    del data['__header__']

    spio.savemat('mat.mat',data)
    print 'Converted mat file size: ', os.path.getsize('mat.mat')/1000, ' kB'

    #Convert into list
    data = data['data'][0][0][0]
    return data

path = 'myrecording.mat'
print 'Original file size: ', os.path.getsize(path)/1000, ' kB'
data = get_data(path)
json_dump(data.tolist())
pickle_dump(data.tolist())
numpy_dump(data)
```

I get an output of:

```
Original file size:  706  kB
Converted mat file size:  4007  kB
JSON file size:  9104  kB
Pickle file size:  10542  kB
NPY file size:  4000  kB
Numpy text file size:  12550  kB
```

Is there anything I can do with the encoding to limit the file size. I would ideally stick with JSON format but I am open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you are open to suggestions: use HDF5 (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/), via either the h5py library (http://code.google.com/p/h5py/) or pytables (http://www.pytables.org).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks a lot for suggestion, I will definitely check it out. I am thinking this may be a conversion issue considering the increase in file size after loadmat followed by savemat and I am wondering whether there is anything to alleviate that.

Comment: The [scipy.io.savemat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html#scipy.io.savemat) command has an argument do_compression that when set to true decreased the size of my data file and made it smaller than my original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Matti says, HDF5 is good to try, and an easy way to implement it is with [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/).

For the time being though, at least compare numpy by using `np.savez_compressed()` instead of `np.save()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help I didn't realize it was the compression issue. I am also going to give a try to HDF5 as was suggested by you and @Matti.

Comment: @Matt The other advantage of using pytables is that it actually will use HDF5 storage during runtime if you have very large arrays, which will save on ram and allow you to have lots of data at once.  (Though I don't use it myself since my datasets are not too large.)

Comment: Great thanks for your help! I am going through the h5py and pytables documentation at the moment :).

Answer (score 1):

JSON is plain text so the files will be bigger than in binary formats. I'd also suggest that you use HDF5.

From http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/:

"HDF5 is a data model, library, and file format for storing and managing data. It supports an unlimited variety of datatypes, and is designed for flexible and efficient I/O and for high volume and complex data."